# Sorting nodes of a undirected graph based on value in Python

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, sorting, graph

I am relatively new to Python. I wrote this code in Python (3.x) to solve a problem which involves an undirected graph.

The expected output of the program should print the node which occurs in the *kth* position from the list of neighbouring nodes of after they are sorted in descending order (based on the value of the node) but if two values are same then the node which comes first when sorted in ascending order of their indices is printed.

If no such node exists then *-1* is printed.

```
n, m, k = input().strip().split(' ')
n, m, k = [int(n), int(m), int(k)]

node_values = list(map(int, input().split(' ')))
d = {}
for i in range(n+1):
    d[i] = []

for i in range(m):
    x, y = input().strip().split(' ')
    x, y = [int(x), int(y)]
    d[x].append(y)
    d[y].append(x)

for key, value in d.items():
    if key != 0:
        if k <= len(value):
            new_list = sorted(value, key=lambda x: node_values[x-1], reverse=True)
            print(new_list[k-1])
        else:
            print(-1)
```

Here, I am sorting using `sort()`, providing the key as the value from `node_values`. But I am confused about adding the second condition (if the values are same then sort them according to the ascending order of their indices).

What am I doing wrong here? Also is it a better choice to use a parallel list for representing the graph over using dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lambda function used to sort can return a tuple, which in your case would be formed as the node values and the index of the node.

```
sorted(value, key=lambda x: (node_values[x-1], x), reverse=True)
```

But you want a different order: descending for the node values and ascending for the indices. This can be achieved by sorting in descending order the negative value of the indices: `x<y => -y < -x`. So you can use this lamba function:

```
sorted(value, key=lambda x: (node_values[x-1], -x), reverse=True)
```

I assumed 'x' is the index of your node but this is not really clear for me.

Comment: I am still getting `list` instead of `tuple` as you have mentioned.

Comment: can you provide a working example so I can test and understand your issue ? (with test data)

Comment: This is the problem: https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/graphs/graph-representation/practice-problems/algorithm/monk-learning-graph-3/  You can find the test data there. Actually the above code works for the test input but the problem arises when two (or more) values are similar

Comment: Actually, the problem is not coherent with the expected solution. It states it is expecting indices in ascending order but the solution data is in descending order... Just use the first lambda of my answer.